# How to share new features in a large multi module project

Tags: project-management, builds, project, maven

I have been working in large multi module projects over a period of time. One major issue I faced is, how to communicate to other teams of a new feature which they may be interested in.
Consider this scenario. Projects X, Y and Z depend on a project P. All depend on version 1.0. Now I work on X and P, do some fixes and add a new feature, and give it version 1.1 (so as to avoid doing something unexpected to Y and Z). Y and Z are unaware of new verion of P.
Subsequently, the version of P may go on with fixes, incompatible changes, features to version 1.2, 1.3 etc.
Is there some way so that folks in Y and Z get to know that there are changes in P, and new features which they may like to incorporate? Thanks.

Comment: Incompatible changes should reflect in changing the major version instead of minor (2.0 instead of 1.2). The rest is a communication issue. It strongly depends on how you communicate in your company or team. You _could_ however define dependencies to always use the newest version, but I would not recommend that.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: communication works the same way as if P would be a component provided by a third party vendor:

- establish a fixed place (web site, file storage, Wiki, dash board, whatever you are using in your organization) where new releases of P are announced and available for download.
- make sure there exists a useful changelog for P, maintained with some discipline, which describes all changes which are visible from a user of P (and not more)
- let the "product owner" of component P actively inform anyone who wants to be informed when there is a new release of P (for example, the product owners of X, Y and Z). Other product owner should be able to choose if they want to be notified for new releases, or if they don't want to be bothered.